# How to fix firebase vulnerability exposed by .git

Tags: git, firebase, security, firebase-hosting

I recently got an email as a result of an alleged open scan: https://smitka.me/

It states:

> The problem is you have a publicly available git repository on your website. You can check it by visiting /.git/HEAD. When you visit the directory /.git you usually get 403 error because there is no index.html/.php file and you don’t allow to show the directory listing/autoindex (if you can see the directory structure you have a misconfigured webserver – it is another type of vulnerability). Despite 403 it is possible to access the files directly. This is the way I found your e-mail address – from the /.git/logs/HEAD – it is the list of commits with details about commiteers.

I am not an expert in this area, and I have simply deployed me site using the firebase console. I have my folder under version control using git, and 
the screenshot will show you the folder structure in the root of the project folder, with hidden files showing.

[image: Folder structure]

In the link posted above, mitigation examples are provided, but I think they are for people with control over their server – I run off firebase hosting and seem to have no such control.

Questions:

1. Is this a security vulnerability?
2. If so, how can i mitigate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the least effort might be to exclude directory `.git` from the deployment, with `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    ...
    "ignore": [
      "README.md",
      "firebase.json",
      ".firebaserc",
      ".git",
      ".gitignore",
      ".idea",
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

the bottom line is: only deploy what is essential to serve the page.

Comment: +1. Another option (and what we normally default to) is have a separate directory for your hosting content (e.g. "public") and move any web assets in there, keep everything else out of the deployment.

Comment: @IanBarber it might be useful, if the default `firebase.json` would exclude all dot-files by wild-card `.*` or `**/.*` ...because this would match `.git` and `.svn`, in terms of preventive security ...or even automatically rejecting all common repository data directory-names while the deployment, so that even deployments with non-default `public` directory could not leak that information.

Comment: This seems like a very fast and efficient way to deal with my existing projects. For future projects, I will take the suggestion by @IanBarber into account.